# With getComponent how to pass props?

Tags: react-router

I can't figure out how to pass props to the component. This is important as I don't want to fetch data in the componentDidMount method as it will then be invisible to search engines.

My code looks like this

```
const router = 
<Route path="/" component={App}>
<IndexRoute onEnter={redirectToLogin} component={LandingPage} />
<Route path="panel" component={ ControlPanel }>
  ...
</Route>
<Route 
  path="/:handle" 
  onEnter={maybeRedirectToHome}
  getComponent={(location, callback)=> {
      getSiteHandleByName(location.pathname.slice(1))
      .then(function(handle){
        if (handle){
          callback(null, Portfolio)
        } else {
          callback(null, NotFound)
        }
      })
      .catch(callback)
  }}
  getChildRoutes={(location, callback)=> {
    callback(null, portfolioRoutes)
  }} 
/>
</Route>
```

I'm trying to serve up a portfolio React App when the user visits a valid url like `mysite.com/thishandleisvalid` but I'll need to also fetch all the content for that app at the `getComponent` point and pass it in as a property. E.g. you might normally do something like this `<Portfolio contentItems={fetchedItems} />`.

Is doing this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is really easy to do with stateless components. Just do something like:

```js
function getComponent(location, callback) {
  const Component = /* ... */;
  const items = /* ... */;

  callback(null, props => <Component {...props} items={items} />);
}
```

The reason we don't explicitly support this sort of pattern is because it's fairly atypical to wire things up this way - for apps that need to deal with this sort of thing, it's much more common to use the `onEnter` hook to e.g. populate a Flux store, then connect the components as appropriate to the relevant stores.

Comment: This works great thanks. And thank you for the info about using the onEnter hook and a flux store. That's still an area I find confusing and need to learn about.

Comment: This works well for me as I'm trying to only pass actions to a component on a per-route basis without polluting the props across the application, say if I used 'React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {'actions': fooActions})' at the app root.

Answer (score 5):

Also if you don't mind accessing props under `route`, you can pass props like this:

**JSX:**

```
<Route 
  path="route_path" 
  customProp="hello"
  getComponent={(location, cb) => {
    // ...
  }}
```

**Programatically:**

```
childRoutes: [
{
  path: 'route_path',
  customProps: 'hello',
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    // ....
  },
```

And `customProp` will be available via `props.route.customProp`

Comment: Exists some documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

currying looks as a simpler way (and even more simpler with recompose/withProps)

```
const getComponentWithProps = (props) =>
  (location, cb) => {
    const Component = /* ... */;
    // ...
    cb(null, withProps(props)(Component))
  }
...
childRoutes: [
  {
    path: 'route_path',
    getComponent: getComponentWithProps({ foo: 'bar' }),
  }
]
```

**UPDATE**

**CAUTION: PERFORMANCE** my version is just a sugaring over taion's answer, and, i suppose, has the same troubles: it causes complete component rerender on rerouting.

it happens because of rewrapping component with withProps enhancer on each new location, that generates new component on each rerouting.

as a quick solution i decided to cache all enhancings in weakmaps. in my case it looks like

```
const getOrAdd = (map) =>
  (value = Function.prototype) =>
    (key) =>
      map.get(key)
        || (
          map.set(
            key,
            value(),
          )
            && map.get(key)
        );

const componentsMap = new WeakMap();
export const getEnhancedMap = getOrAdd(componentsMap)(() => new WeakMap());

export const getEnhancedComponent = (
  component,
  enhancer,
) => {
  const enhancedMap = getEnhancedMap(component);
  return getOrAdd(enhancedMap)(() => enhancer(component))(enhancer);
}
```